# Proof based on euclidean geometry

Tags: solution-verification, euclidean-geometry

> Let $ABCD$ be a quadrilateral and $X$ be the mid-point of $BD$. Prove that the area of $AXCB$ is one-half the area of $ABCD.$

I tried by taking  $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle ABX$ first, since both of them have the same height and $BX= \frac 12 BD$,

Area of $\triangle ABD = \frac 12 \text{ area of } \triangle ABX$

Similarly,
$\triangle BCD$ is twice of $\triangle BCX$.

And this is the way I tried to prove it, but I am not confident enough to say that it's a proper proof

Can anyone guide me on whether I am correct or wrong ?

Comment: I think you are on the right track

Comment: Is the quadrilateral assumed to be complex? I am pretty certain this doesn't hold for, say, a dart.

Comment: Well, it is not mentioned, but I guess it's not a complex quadrilateral...

Comment: It is the other way round. [△BCD] is ***twice*** of [△BCX].

Comment: Oh yeah, I wrote that by mistake, thanks for the correction